# Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled - Again

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm new to WCF and I've been hitting my head for the past week trying to get everything to work.  When browsing the service.svc file I receive the message about the metadata not being enabled.  There's hundreds of posts on this but I must be missing something.  I think I followed the instructions correctly but I still can't find my error.  Where am I going wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

service.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService" Debug="true" %>
```

web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="BiteSizeLearningWS.iServiceInterface" behaviorConfiguration="TranscriptServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService" />

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TranscriptServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

ServiceContract

```
namespace BiteSizeLearningWS
{
    [ServiceContract (Name="TranscriptService")]
    public interface iServiceInterface{...
```

Implementation

```
public class TranscriptService : iServiceInterface
```

Global.asax

```
namespace BiteSizeLearningWS
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("TranscriptService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(TranscriptService)));  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your:

`<service name="BiteSizeLearningWS.iServiceInterface"...`

*name* attribute value and the

`<endpoint address="" ... contract="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService" />`

*contract* attribute value mixed up. Try this:

`<service name="BiteSizeLearningWS.TranscriptService"...`

and

`<endpoint address="" ... contract="BiteSizeLearningWS.iServiceInterface" />`

If that works, then what happened is that WCF used the automatic default configuration values for the service instead of the invalid configuration shown in the question. The metadata endpoint is **not** enabled by default which would be why you're seeing the "disabled" message.

Comment: Thank you Sixto.  That solved the error and moved me on to the next step.  Thank you.